# I need to solve one equation, but I dont know how to solve equation with floor functions

Tags: proof-verification, binary, ceiling-and-floor-functions, binary-operations

Im a student with not such a knowledge to solve equations with floor functions. I want to ask, if it is even possible and if it so, how is possible to prove this equation to be true.

```
- ⌊(n+m)/G⌋ = ⌊(2g-n-m)/G⌋-1
```

and where :

```
  G= b^r 
  g= b^r - 1
```

when needed , r and b can be replaced by any natural number

Edit1 : 
I only need to prove it when G= 2^r and g = 2^r-1 where r is variable

Edit2 : One of the variables, n or m can be fixed.

Comment: What is n,m,a,b,g,G,r? All different variables? There are way too many variables for this to be remotely solvable.

Comment: I already changed it , there are just variables n,m,G and g . But i only need to prove it when G= 2^r and g = 2^r-1 where r is variable

Comment: also it is possible to fix one of the variable so for example n=0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $G=2^r$; $g=2^r-1$ and $n+m=k$ then we have
$$- \Big\lfloor\frac{k}{2^r}\Big\rfloor = \Big\lfloor\frac{2^{r+1}-2-k}{2^r}\Big\rfloor-1$$
$$\Big\lfloor\frac{k}{2^r}\Big\rfloor+\Big\lfloor\frac{2^{r+1}-2-k}{2^r}\Big\rfloor=1$$
$$\Big\lfloor\frac{k}{2^r}\Big\rfloor+\Big\lfloor2-\frac{k+2}{2^r}\Big\rfloor=1$$
As $k\gt0$ we need one of the floor expressions to evaluate to $0$ and the other evaluate to $1$ in order for this to be true. This occurs when
$$2^r\le k\le2^{r+1}-2$$
So a valid solution is any values of $n,m$ such that
$$G\le n+m\le2g$$
If you fix one of the variables, for example $n=0$ then we have a range of solutions
$$G\le m\le2g$$

Comment: thank you so much, now I know I did some error before this conclusion, because it is not fitting to my case, I think I will make another thread completely describing my case, but anyways, thank you man